# C++ "Request for member 'push_back'

Tags: c++, vector

here is my code:

```
void MyWork::computeDistances()
{

int column = sentence1.size();
int row = sentence2.size();
//int min = 0;

dist.resize(column);

for (int i = 0; i < column; i++){
    dist[i].resize(row);
}

for (int i = 0; i < column; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < row; j++){
        cout << "A" << endl;
        if (i == 0){

            if (sentence1[j] == sentence2[i]){
                dist[i][j].push_back(0);
```

In the main file, I have declared the 2D vector as :

```
vector<vector<int> > dist;
```

However, I get an error:

```
MyWork.cpp:30:17: error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘(&((MyWork*)this)->MyWork::dist.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Tp = std::vector<int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::vector<int> >, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference = std::vector<int>&, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int](((unsigned int)i)))->std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Tp = int, _Alloc = std::allocator<int>, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference = int&, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int](((unsigned int)j))’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
```

I think this has something to do with passing by reference but I'm not sure what. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Nothing related to how you pass your argument.

`dist` is a `vector<vector<int> >`

`dist[i]` is a `vector<int>`

`dist[i][j]` is an `int`, which you're calling `operator[]` on. That won't work.

I believe you want `dist[i][j] = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

```
   dist[i][j].push_back(0);
```

`dist[i][j]` has type **int**, it does not have `push_back` member function.

It depends on what you really want to do, a simple change could be:

```
  dist[i][j] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your definition, dist is a vector of vector of int, thus  dist[i] is a vector of int thus dist[i][j] is an int.  You can't pushback on an int.